# How to purge all rabbitmq queues in python by queue name

Tags: python, rabbitmq, message-queue

I use the python `kombu` package for interacting with a rabbitmq service.
I want to purge all queues. I saw there is a `kombu.Queue.purge` method, but I don't want to create `kombu.Queue` objects as I don't know which exchanges are connected to which queues. I just want to use the queue name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the kombu `Channel` class that implements a `queue_purge` method that purge a queue given its name.

The following code list all queues and purge them, given their name.

```py
from kombu import Connection

# Create a connection
mq_conn_string = 'amqp://user:password@domain:port//'  # Set the correct credentials
mq_conn = Connection(mq_conn_string)
mq_conn.connect()

# Create a channel
channel = mq_conn.channel()

# Get all queues
vhost = "/"
manager = mq_conn.get_manager()
queues = manager.get_queues(vhost)

# Purge each queue
for queue in queues:
    queue_name = queue["name"]
    channel.queue_purge(queue_name)
```