# Powershell script to Purge all RabbitMQ queues for all vhosts

Tags: windows, powershell, rabbitmq

I'm runnings tests thath fills RabbitMQ queues with messages. I have multiple vhosts and each host has multiple queues with lots of messages. I want a Powershell script that will simply purge all messages from all queues for all vhosts. There is already a [script for Python that purges all queues for a single vhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64229912/how-to-purge-all-rabbitmq-queues-in-python-by-queue-name), but I want to use powershell and I want to purge all queues for all vhosts.

I don't want to delete the queues or vhosts, I only want to purge the queues of all messages. I'm using RabbitMQ version 3.12.10.

Does anyone have such a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a powershell script based [on the 'rabbitmqctl' documentation.](https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html) 
The script uses 3 `rabbitmqctl` commands:

1. `rabbitmqctl list_vhosts > vhosts.txt` Which fetches a list of all vhosts and stores the list to a file.
2. `rabbitmqctl list_queues -p $vhost > queues.txt` Which fetches a list of all queues for a given vhost, and stores the queue names to a file.
3. `rabbitmqctl purge_queue -p $vhost $queueName` Which purges a given queue for a give vhost.

Remember to **add the RabbitMQ bin dir to you environment Path variable** to enable `rabbitmqctl` in the powershell terminal. The script is filtering out some of the generic progam output, so based on what version of RabbitMQ you are using and you environment, **you may have to modify the script to work for you.**

Here's the script:

```
rabbitmqctl list_vhosts > vhosts.txt
foreach($vhost in Get-Content .\vhosts.txt) {
    if ($vhost.StartsWith("Listing vhosts") -or $vhost.StartsWith("name")) {    # skipping the generic program output
        continue;
    }
    Write-Host "Checking vhost $($vhost) for queues"
    rabbitmqctl list_queues -p $vhost > queues.txt

    foreach ($queueLine in Get-Content .\queues.txt) {
        if ($queueLine.StartsWith("Timeout: ") -or $queueLine.StartsWith("Listing queues") -or $queueLine.StartsWith("name")) { # skipping the generic program output
            continue;
        }
        $split = $queueLine -split "\s+"    # splitting string on both space and tab
        $queueName = $split[0]
        $messageCount = $split[1]
        if ($messageCount -eq 0 ) {
            continue;
        }
        rabbitmqctl purge_queue -p $vhost $queueName
    }
}
Remove-Item "vhosts.txt"
Remove-Item "queues.txt"
```